# How to set jFormattedTextField so it only allows 2 numbers?

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I'm a beginner in Java, and NetBeans. I'm trying to make a simple program where you introduce 2 numbers and their sum gets divided by two. However, I'm using `JFormattedTExtField`s and I don't know how to customize the allowed input in them. Basically I'm trying to find out how to:

- Only allow numbers to be entered in `JFormmatedTextField`;
- Only allow a certain amount of numbers;

Comment: may be you have look at JSpinner too,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a NumberFormat and specify the maximum number of integer digits with [setMaximumIntegerDigits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMaximumIntegerDigits%28int%29).

Here's a nice [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html).

Basically you can do something like:

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(); 
f.setMaximumIntegerDigits(maxDigitsAmount);
JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(f);
```

The [Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/Format.html) should guarantee that the inserted String satisfy the format. Anyway even if a number is supplied, the textfield will store it as a String. So if you need your original Integer you need to rebuild it like suggested @noise:

```
Integer i = Integer.toString(field.getText());
```

Comment: Thanks! Oh and another thing. If anyone can tell me how to set the text of a textfield to an int? Example, I have 2 ints(The values entered in the 2 text boxes) and a rezult int, which is equal to the sum of the 2 ints. If I call the jTextField1.setText(rezult) it asks for string instead of int. Any help?

Comment: Thanks alot guys. I've almost fixed it, except when I call JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(f); it gives me an error "Cannot find symbol JFormattedTextField". Any idea?

Comment: you should include javax.swing.JFormattedTextField