# A DecimalFormat pattern for a single digit between 1-9

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, formatting

I'm writing a Sudoku board in Java and opted to use the `JFormattedTextField` class for the board cells because I can have a control about the input with providing a correct `DecimalFormat` object.

My question is, what String should I use in the constructor of the `DecimalFormat` so that it would represent a pattern of a single digit between 1-9.

Alternatively, is there a better class(es) to use for that purpose?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, please look this existing post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637792/how-to-set-jformattedtextfield-so-it-only-allows-2-numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
    String pattern = "#";
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
    decimalFormat.setMaximumIntegerDigits(1);      
    String format = decimalFormat.format(number);
```